# Type checking doesn't work with JSON.parse()?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.0

couldn't find a proper explanation why type checking doesn't work with JSON.parse(), can someone shed some light on it? Example:

```
> let n: number = 1
undefined
> typeof n
'number'
> n = true
⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript: [eval].ts (1,1): Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'number'. (2322)
> typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(true))
'boolean'
> n = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(true))
true
> typeof n
'boolean'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because if you see the type definition for `JSON.parse`, it returns `any`:

```
parse(text: string, reviver?: (key: any, value: any) => any): any;
```

Which means that type checking will be disabled on the parsed output. You can learn more about the [`any` type in the official documentation.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#any)

Comment: That's what I was thinking... But then, why does the typeof of the value is `boolean`?


    > typeof JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(true))
    'boolean'

Comment: Because that is the runtime type. TypeScript cannot know that at compile time.

Comment: Maybe it's this distinction between compile time checking and runtime checking that's making this confusing. So, Typescript won't check types at all during runtime?

Comment: Correct. Everything TypeScript does is compile-time only.

Comment: That's fine, got it.